# Why simple mysql query takes too long?

Tags: mysql

I really give up. Mysql server suddenly got working very slowly. 
I have mysql server 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - (Ubuntu).
The machine is pretty powerful, 50 cores, 300GB RAM. I did not have problems, more over before I had bigger loading to DB. Last time I have decreased and optimized queries.

But really simple query may hang for long time:

```
# Query_time: 12.173414  Lock_time: 0.000053 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1582047698;
UPDATE `account`
                  SET `field` = `field` + 1, `last_day` = `last_day` + 1 
                  WHERE `id` = 61449;
```

Table account consists 30000 rows.

The mysql config is:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]



#skip-grant-tables

bind-address=0.0.0.0

max_allowed_packet         = 2000MB

log_error = 0
general_log = 0
wait_timeout = 28800
interactive_timeout = 28800
innodb_log_buffer_size = 500M
innodb_log_file_size = 2047M

connect_timeout=360
open_files_limit = 5000
max_connections = 5000

[mysqld_safe]
```

Multithreaded application is run and threads perform queries to DB, especially to account table.
And there are not many queries. Maybe about 30 queries per minute.

And another interesting moment: there is table session, and nothing performs queries to session table, excepts php script, when user update page. And I am only user, and there is only 1 update query to session table, but this also hangs, simple query:

```
# Query_time: 5.971559  Lock_time: 0.000055 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1582047736;
UPDATE `session` SET `data`='__flash|a:0:{}__id|i:10;__expire|i:1582049525;lastReferrer-|s:29:\"/mail/index\";lastReferrer-account|s:14:\"/account/index\";lastReferrer-mail|s:20:\"/mail/index\";', `user_id`=10, `timestamp`=1582047730, `useragent`='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/564 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.34567.130 Safari/537.36', `expire`=1582049530 WHERE `id`='fsdadfadsafdsfds';
```

Table session consists only 50 rows.

Probably my description doesn't full and doesn't explain the situation well. I am just confused why it may happen. As I said it worked well with bigger loading, and it must work perfect on such powerful machine.

Of course, I tried restart mysql, apache2, and whole machine...

Comment: Is `id` the primary key of accounts table? Have you tried optimizing the table?

Comment: sure id is primary, optimized!

Comment: This is a question for the [DBA site](https://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there my be something subtle that we are missing.  Such as the Engine or Datatype.

Comment: `max_allowed_packet         = 2000MB` -- 1GB is the limit!  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?